# Python re.split how to split on multiple patterns specified from variables

Tags: python-3.x, split, python-re

I am trying to split a string on multiple sub strings, but I can not get re.split() to accept 2 variables as the patterns. I see multiple example of how to use individual characters or combinations of special characters as patterns, but nothing about using variables.

These are dummy inputs. The strings will be more complicated, change based on other factors, and may occur multiple times.

```
string_to_split = "This_is_the_string_to_split"
pattern1 = "_is_"
pattern2 = "_to_"
```

Desired Resut:

```
# ['This', 'the_string', 'split']
```

I can split specifying either pattern alone, or the values of the patterns when specified as a regex

```
re.split(pattern1, string_to_split)
# ['This', 'the_string_to_split']
re.split(pattern2, string_to_split)
# ['This_is_the_string', 'split']
re.split(r'_is_|_to_', string_to_split)
# ['This', 'the_string', 'split']
```

I can not use the variable names (pattern1, pattern2) to both be used simultaneously

```
re.split(pattern1|pattern2, string_to_split)
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'str'
re.split(r'pattern1|pattern2', string_to_split)
['This_is_the_string_to_split']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine the patterns and the '|' operator using string concatenation:

`re.split(pattern1 + "|" + pattern2, string_to_split)`